# Mockit redefineMethod not working because of interface or generic abstract

Tags: java, generics, testng, jmockit

I'm trying to figure out why Mockit is not working for the following code:

```
public class TestClass {
    @Test
    public void test() {
        Mockit.redefineMethods(ExecuterClass.class, new Object() {
            @SuppressWarnings("unused")
            public SomeService getService() {
                return new MockSomeServiceImpl();
            }
        });

        // Code to run test
    }
}

public abstract class ExecuterClass<T,U,V,W> {
    // Other methods/variables
    public SomeService getService() {
        return someProvider.getService();
    }
} 

public interface SomeService {
    // Some method definitions
}

public class MockSomeServiceImpl implements SomeService {
    // Some method implementations
}
```

The error I get back is:

```
java.lang.IllegalAccessError: tried to access class TestClass from class ExecuterClass
```

Any ideas on how to fix this?? In the end, I would like the test to use the MockSomeServiceImpl methods rather than those in SomeService implementation.

SomeService was generated by a WSDL, so I don't have the implementation that someObject.getService() returns. So I can't do Mockit.redefineMethods(SomeServiceImpl.class, MockSomeServiceImpl.class)